# Maven (MVN) return value on failure?

Tags: maven, batch-file

When we run mvn clean install from a batch (*.cmd) script, %ERRORLEVEL% is always 0 regardless if the build completes sucessfully or fails.  How can you get Maven to return a non zero code for failures?

```
mvn clean install   
echo error:%ERRORLEVEL%
```

We're using Maven 2.

---

Update:

Note that if we do "mvn blah" then ERRORLEVEL=1 after the failure due to the bad target.

But if we do "mvn clean install" where the build fails due to a complication error we still get ERRORLEVEL=0.

---

Update 2:

Ok, this is because we are running Maven like:

mvn clean install | tee %LOGFILE%

I guess it's tee that is setting the ERRORLEVEL.

Comment: mvn is a batch file have you tried to use call mvn clean install and the output the ERRORLEVEL ?

Comment: What is the exact version of Maven 2 that you are using? There was a bug in maven 2 that it didn't return the correct error code: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3651. The bug was fixed in maven 2.1.  If you are using an earlier version you could simply apply the fix manually to your local bat file.

Comment: We're using Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is because we are running Maven like:

mvn clean install | tee %LOGFILE%

I guess it's tee that is setting the ERRORLEVEL.